# What is the earliest android version a modern app should to be compatible with?

Tags: android, compatibility

since a few weeks i get in touch with app testing in espresso and junit and the question of compatibility came to my mind.
Which is the earliest android version an modern app should be at least runnable? 
Thanks!

Comment: That depends how you are distributing the app. Google Play store has a minimum version that changes frequently but maybe you're using something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your public, but if you want to have a more general idea you can look at the distribution of devices running a certain version of Android [here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards).

As you can see, if you want to target the majority of devices, it could be a good idea to target from version 4.4 (API 19) onwards.

Comment: Thanks, thats what i needed!